# Why my Common mode choke with 2 turns showing multiple Peaks in the graph?

Tags: ltspice, s-parameters, vna, common-mode-choke, characterization

I analyzed the [CMC choke](https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/Wurth-Elektronik/744830039080?qs=NSAOzM2zc%2FWamGB%252BtRpxRw%3D%3D) by Wurth Electronics (part no: 744830039080) using VNA and obtained the insertion loss for both common mode and differential mode.

[image: common mode insertion loss]

[image: Differential mode insertion loss]

The graphs match with the datasheet:

[image: Insertion loss from Datasheet]

While attempting to replicate the data in LTspice, the downloaded SPICE file from Wurth did not produce multiple peaks or resonances as shown in the datasheet graph:

[image: Spice simulation for Single resonance of common mode connection in comparison with library file]

I was able to optimize the common-mode impedance with the datasheet for the first resonance peak. How can I optimize the graph to reflect the measured results accurately with multiple resonances?

Comment: Alaska -  Hi, Currently your question breaks the [site rule on referencing](/help/referencing) material copied/adapted from elsewhere. To comply with that rule, please [edit] the question & add the **name** of the PDF / video / webpage (in this case, it's a datasheet, so probably a PDF) which is the source of the graph, and its **link**. Also please remember it's your responsibility to follow that rule in future too. TY (Please see the [tour] & [help] as site rules here differ from typical forums.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple resonance frequencies of common-mode choke](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/699821/multiple-resonance-frequencies-of-common-mode-choke) While the question is not really a duplicate, it turns out the one answer covers, quite possibly, everything you're looking for and more(!).

Comment: I don't have an IEEE membership, but if you do I believe these papers might be relevant:  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7468314 |||  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9862235